# Unable to open .jar file in qtp

Tags: jar, command, qtp, hp-uft

i have written a .vbs file with below code.

```
Set WshShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "cmd.exe"

WScript.Sleep 10000

WshShell.SendKeys "cd\"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

strUser = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName

WshShell.SendKeys "cd c:\users\"
WshShell.SendKeys strUser
WshShell.SendKeys "\desktop"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WshShell.SendKeys "Java -jar "
fileName=inputbox("Please enter the .jar file name(without .jar extension)")

WScript.Sleep 10000

WshShell.SendKeys fileName
WshShell.SendKeys ".jar"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

and im trying to run this file using systemutil.run function in qtp. It is running properly but at the end it is showing "Unable to create java virtual machine".

if i try to double click the .vbs file it will open my .jar file.

Please help me.

Comment: What happen if you combine `fileName` and `.jar` and send them together?

Comment: that is not the issue... What my concern is why is not working from UFT and works if i double click on my .vbs file

Comment: What Java version you have? 32 bit or 64 bit?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I haven't tried but it should work. try:

```
fileName=inputbox("Please enter the .jar file name(without .jar extension)")
SystemUtil.Run "cmd","/c java -jar " & fileName & ".jar",""
```

Just change the path.
Check **[this](http://www.joecolantonio.com/2011/07/18/qtp-have-you-ever-wanted-to-simply-call-a-jar-file-or-java-class-from-qtp-but-wasn%E2%80%99t-sure-how/)** link for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You're running into this issue because Java is trying to use more ram than you have available.  Try running the jar while allocating less ram "Java -Xmx512M -jar "